# Complexity of a randomly-traveled N * M grid using backtracking

Tags: c, algorithm, grid, complexity-theory, backtracking

I made an algorithm that compute a random-path across a N*M grid using backtracking.
It start at [N / 2][0] and shall finish at [N / 2][M - 1].
Each iteration he choose a random direction (Left, Right, forward) and keep going recursively. The selected direction  is kept in memory so that it each node don't use the same twice.
When the node meet a already-used node or the boundary of the grid and each direction has been tested then it pull up back on the stack.

It works perfectly but I wonder how to calculate the complexity of the problem depending of the size of the grid.

I'm sorry for my bad english, if I forgot to tell something then please ask me the information you need.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Time the run of the algorithm with varying M and varying N.  Use a spreadsheet to plot the results on a log scale.   Check out the gradient.

Comment: Also, please show your perfectly-working code:)

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you cannot talk about deterministic running time here, because, theoretically, once stuck in a loop (e.g. you meet a node you've already visited) the random could keep returning the same direction forever (although the probability of this happening is very small). In other words, you're describing what we call a [randomized algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm) (roughly any algorithm that uses random bits to guide its execution; this means that the running time is a random variable).

Instead you can talk about [*expected* running time](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159507/what-does-it-mean-by-expected-running-time-and-average-runnnig-time-of-an-algor), that is,  the expected number of operations before the algorithm returns a random path.

Do consider providing a working code for the algorithm so that we can give a more concrete answer.

Comment: The chosen direction is kept in memory so it don't use it again. I'm sorry but I can't show the code for some reason. Thanks for your  answer.

Comment: Oh, okay; but you chose the new direction at random? Can you provide a pseudocode which we can use to do the analysis?

Comment: If you have `while ((newDirection = randomDirectino()) != oldDirection) {` then what I said about the time complexity still applies.

Comment: Nope, we randomize only the order in which the possible choices are tested. Like [Left Up Right] or [Up Left Right]. So there is no infinite loop or anything like that. We want time complexity, not statistics.

Comment: Ok. But the worst-case bound will be pessimistic.

Comment: 'I can't show the code for some reason' - what would that be?   If you don't show the code, some might suspect that it does not exist, I couldn't possibly comment myself.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Dijkstra's algorithm without the path length.  From this point of view, your problem is not a general graph, so you can take advantage of its structure.

Specifically, since you are marking your nodes so you don't repeat them, and each node has no more than 4 edges, the worst case is proportional to the number of nodes:  O(MN).  On the other hand the best case (unlikely as it is) would be to randomly choose a shortest path, which would be O(M).

Since you are choosing directions randomly, for any given M and N, there should be a well-defined distribution of execution times.  Unfortunately, an exact analysis seems difficult:  easily analyzed cases, such as a random walk, do not apply here because marking nodes changes the statistics at each step, and because your rectangular arena is a complex shape from an analysis point of view.

I will wave my hands and say that you can expect most of your distribution should be closer to O(MN), since you can expect the odd [self-avoiding walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) that results will generally not head in the right direction;  this would put your expected execution time at O(MN) as well.  There will be a small number of cases where it does head in the right direction, and encounters the target before it checks a significant proportion of all nodes; I would expect that the proportion of these lucky cases should be ~ 1/M of the total distribution, and should take something like O(M^p) steps where p is some fractional exponent between 1 and 2.  Run times approaching the best case will be on an exponential tail down from this region.

If N << M, then lucky cases might be more like ~1/N of the total distribution; and if MN << M^p the exponential tail would be all that is left of the "lucky" case...

However, this is just informed guessing, not a proper analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis !

Comment: I enjoyed reading the answer; we need more answers like this one on StackOverflow. :-)